# How to return value on addOnCompleteListener Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have a login activity that connect to my firebase app. I want to return a value on complete listener.

```
class LoginDataSource {

    private lateinit var user: LoggedInUser

    fun login(username: String, password: String, mAuth: FirebaseAuth): Result<LoggedInUser> {
        try {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update object with the signed-in user's information
                        val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
                        if (currentUser != null) {
                            user = LoggedInUser(currentUser.uid, currentUser.email!!)
                        }
                        return Result.Success(user)
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.d("Login", "createUserWithEmail:failure")
                    }
                }

            return Result.Success(user)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            return Result.Error(IOException("Error logging in", e))
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

My class LoginRepository

```
class LoginRepository(val dataSource: LoginDataSource) {

    fun login(username: String, password: String, mAuth: FirebaseAuth): Result<LoggedInUser> {
        // handle login
        val result = dataSource.login(username, password, mAuth)

        if (result is Result.Success) {
            setLoggedInUser(result.data)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

My class LoginViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel(private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _loginForm = MutableLiveData<LoginFormState>()
    val loginFormState: LiveData<LoginFormState> = _loginForm

    private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
    val loginResult: LiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResult

    fun login(username: String, password: String, mAuth: FirebaseAuth) {
        // can be launched in a separate asynchronous job
        val result = loginRepository.login(username, password, mAuth)

        if (result is Result.Success) {
            _loginResult.value = LoginResult(success = LoggedInUserView(displayName = result.data.displayName))
        } else {
            _loginResult.value = LoginResult(error = R.string.login_failed)
        }
    }
}
```

These code are template from Activity Login when first time create an app. Any suggestion?

Comment: Show me why you need return value inside? onComplete callback is void method so it means it not allow return type

Comment: @CôngHải I need get the value from my login view model, i updated my question above

Answer (score 1):

instead of returning the value in the listener, you can call a function, for example

```
fun gotResult(user: LoggedInUser){
// you can do your logic here, once you get the result
}
```

change `return Result.Success(user)` to `gotResult(user)`

hope this can help

UPDATE:

as you are using viewmodel and livedata, you can pass a livedata to the login call

`fun login(username: String, password: String, mAuth: FirebaseAuth, user: MutableLiveData<LoggedInUser>)`

your `LoginViewModel` will subscribe to this data and the `LoginDataSource` will change it onComplete

Answer (score 1):

"addOnCompleteListener" does not have return type means it is an Unit return type. Therefore "addOnCompleteListener" can not return any value. To get any update value from this listener, need to call a method on passed object like this -

I have created a FirebaseManager kotlin class having registration method -

```
class FirebaseManager private constructor() {

private var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()   

var registrationResult: Result<RegistrationResult>? = null

fun registerWithEmail(
    registrationForm: RegistrationForm,
    registrationDao: RegistrationDao
) {

    try {
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            registrationForm.email,
            registrationForm.password
        ).addOnCompleteListener { task ->

            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val firebaseUser = task.result!!.user

                registrationResult = Result.Success(
                    RegistrationResult(
                        RegistrationView(
                            firebaseUser.uid,
                            firebaseUser.email
                        )
                    )
                )

                registrationDao.registrationCallback(registrationResult)

            } else {
                Timber.e(task.exception!!, "Exception while registering an user ")
                registrationResult = Result.Error(task.exception!!)
                registrationDao.registrationCallback(registrationResult)
            }

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Timber.e(it, "Exception while registering an user ")
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e, "Exception while registering an user")
    }
}


companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var instance: FirebaseManager? = null

    fun getInstance(): FirebaseManager {
        return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: FirebaseManager().also { instance = it }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And RegistrationDao Class has a call back method. The kotlin class is -

class RegistrationDao private constructor(private val firebaseManager: FirebaseManager) :
AppDao<RegistrationForm, RegistrationResult> {

```
override fun save(input: RegistrationForm): Unit {
    firebaseManager.registerWithEmail(input, this)
}

fun registrationCallback(registrationResult: Result<RegistrationResult>?){
    Timber.i("registrationResult $registrationResult")
}



companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var instance: RegistrationDao? = null

    fun getInstance(firebaseManager: FirebaseManager): RegistrationDao {
        return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: RegistrationDao(firebaseManager).also { instance = it }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Other than this some model class used to move input and output data.

Comment: perfect thanks bawa

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I needed to check registration result, and if it is success I will move into another activity, using `livedata` and `viewmodel` here is what I did to make it work:

viewmodel:

```
private var _accountCreationResult = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val accountCreationResult get() = _accountCreationResult


override fun createUser(user: MutableLiveData<User>,result: MutableLiveData<Boolean>,context: Context) {
    _userLiveData = user
   authService.createUser(user,_accountCreationResult,context)
}
```

Authentication Service:

```
override fun createUser(user: MutableLiveData<User>,result:MutableLiveData<Boolean>,context: Context) {
    if (user.value!=null)
    {
            firebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.value!!.email,user.value!!.password)
            .addOnCompleteListener  {authResult ->
                if (authResult.isSuccessful){
                    user.postValue(User(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid,user.value!!.email,
                        user.value!!.password,""))
                    result.postValue(true)
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Account Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    newsRepository.addUser(User(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid,user.value!!.email,"",user.value!!.name))
                }else{
                    result.postValue(false)
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Failed to create account: ${authResult.exception?.localizedMessage}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

my fragment:

```
    binding.signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
        val fullName = binding.nameTf.editText?.text.toString()
        val email = binding.emailTf.editText?.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordTf.editText?.text.toString()
        val user = User("", email, password,fullName)
        val userLiveData = MutableLiveData<User>()
        userLiveData.value = user

        if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModel.createUser(userLiveData,viewModel.accountCreationResult,requireContext())
                viewModel.accountCreationResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner
                ) {
                    if (it){
                        val intent = Intent(context,NewsMainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }


        } else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fields can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

`createUser()` is a method from an interface that I have created, `User` is the data model that I also created to hold user information. I am also saving the new user information to `firestore` using `newsRepository.addUser`(except for the password I leave empty for security) because I did not find a way to store the user full name(and maybe some other user informations later) in the Firebase Authentication service.